# Perl - Writing Strings/Scalar Values to CSV with Text::CSV

Tags: csv, perl, export-to-csv

I am trying to write connection success/failure to a CSV file pulled from multiple databases so I can verify my eval works and that a failed connection doesn't make the script stop. There's a CSV file that has the database hostname and schema to use, which I loop through. I can read the file in without any trouble but I'm having some trouble writing specific values to the file as a sort of 'formatting' to display the data and to test the DBI connection.

Initially, I tried just using multiple print statements but that didn't work. I tried converting the strings and scalars into an array ref like Perl reported. When I created the arrays and put in an array ref, I didn't have any errors but I only got the reference. But I need the text printed out.

The code I'm using is below and there's a few commented lines of what I was trying before, which didn't work. The eval is there for writing if a connection to a database fails and which location it was.

I know I'm doing something incorrectly, otherwise it would be working. However, I don't know exactly where I'm going wrong.

```
# Instantiate Report Data CSV
my $reportCsv = Text::CSV->new();
$reportCsv->eol ("\n");
$reportCsv->sep_char (",");
$reportCsv->quote_char ("\"");
$reportCsv->always_quote (1);
$reportCsv->escape_char ("\\");
$reportCsv->strict (1);

# Open stores.csv for processing
open my $storesFile, "<:encoding(utf8)", "stores.csv" or $logger->logdie("Failed to open stores.csv.");
open my $reportOutput, ">:encoding(utf8)", "report.csv" or $logger->logdie("Failed to generate CSV.");

# Read the file and dump to another CSV
while (<$storesFile>) {
    if ($storeCsv->parse($_)) {
        my @storeInfo = $storeCsv->fields();
        my @successArray = [$storeInfo[0], "\n", "---------------\n", "Connected to $storeInfo[2] at $storeInfo[1].\n\n"];
        my @failureArray = [$storeInfo[0], "\n", "---------------\n", "Failed to connect to store database.\n\n"];
        #print "$storeInfo[0], $storeInfo[1], $storeInfo[2]\n";
        eval {
            my $storeConnection = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$storeInfo[2];host=$storeInfo[1];port=3306", "username", "password", { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 }) or $logger->error("Failed to connect to database.");
        };
        if ($@) {
            $reportCsv->print($reportOutput, \@failureArray);
            #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "\n");
            #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "---------------\n");
            #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "Failed to connect to store database.\n\n");
        }
        $reportCsv->print($reportOutput, \@successArray);
        #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "\n");
        #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "---------------\n");
        #$reportCsv->print($reportOutput, "Connected to $storeInfo[2] at $storeInfo[1].\n\n");
    } else {
        my $inputError = $storeCsv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $inputError" or $logger->error($inputError);
    }
}
```

Comment: `my @a = [ ];` should be `my @a = ( );`

Comment: `[ ]` creates an array and a reference to it, and returns the reference (a scalar). You are assigning a single scalar to your array.

Comment: Tip: You should always use `->binary(1)`, and `while (<$storesFile>) {
    if ($storeCsv->parse($_)) { ... }}}
        my @storeInfo = $storeCsv->fields();` should be `while ( my $storeInfo = $storeCsv->getline($storesFile) ) { ... }`

Comment: It was my arrays. That was tripping me up. I've got it working. Thanks!